# iOS - Saving battery after sleep mode is disable by setIdleTimerDisabled by decreasing the brightness level

Tags: ios, iphone, battery, battery-saver

I need my app to stay awake and not to enter sleep mode. So I used setIdleTimerDisabled method on application object. It works perfectly. I just wondered whether it is possible to save battery somehow after doing so.

Is it possible to prevent app to enter sleep mode but enable the automatic decreasing of the brightness level? I mean when the idleTimerDisabled is set to NO - it will automatically lower the brightness after several seconds and then after 1-5 minutes (depends on settings) it will go to sleeping mode. I want to turn off the sleeping mode but preserve the brightness adjustment. Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

Eventually, I implemented "touchesBegan:" in the main controller where I always reset NSTimer and set the brightness level to maximum. If the NSTimer expires (30 secs), the brightness level is set to lower value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible :

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:yourvalue];
```

Comment: Yes but this is not automatic adjustment of the brightness. I need decrease the brightness level only if the user is not touching the screen for a while..

Comment: It's not difficult to code. Yon can  record each time the user touch the screen and then decrease the brightness if the ellapsed time is superior to the desired value. And I think the answer to your question is no, there is no such thing than can be done automatically.